# Making a rotated (vertcal) UISlider look pretty

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, uikit, core-graphics

I'm currently designing an application that aims to make use of vertical UI sliders. The consensus on SO seems to be that, in order to create a vertical UI slider in iOS, you must use a transformation function to rotate the control with UIKit.

When I actually do use one, my slider ends up looking very imprecise and ugly:

[image: Vertical UI slider issue]

Aside from simply starting from scratch with a totally new NSControl built from the ground up to be a vertical slider, does anyone have an idea of how to make a vertical UI slider look less aliased?

Code used to generate slider:

```
_slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kWTFSliderHeight, 10)];
_slider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 1.5);
[self addSubview:_slider];
```

Thanks, --Dany.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you used to rotate the slider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that an (untransformed) `UISlider` ignores the frame height you request and uses a frame height of 23.  For example I did this:

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 100, 40, 10)];
[self.view addSubview:slider];
```

and here's the resulting frame:

```
(gdb) po [[(id)UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
<UIWindow: 0x6c1c9a0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x6c1ca30>>
   | <UIView: 0x6c23160; frame = (0 20; 320 460); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6c22750>>
   |    | <UISlider: 0x6c22ad0; frame = (80 100; 40 23); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6c21ae0>; value: 0.000000>
```

and its center point:

```
(gdb) p (CGPoint)[0x6c22ad0 center]
$1 = {
  x = 100, 
  y = 111.5
}
```

Notice that its center is at a half-point coordinate on the Y axis.  If you rotate the slider by a right angle like this:

```
slider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 1.5);
```

its center doesn't change but its frame does:

```
(gdb) po [[(id)UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
<UIWindow: 0x6a3a000; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x6a36780>>
   | <UIView: 0x6a3c420; frame = (0 20; 320 460); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a3ba10>>
   |    | <UISlider: 0x6a3bd90; frame = (88.5 91.5; 23 40); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a3be20>; value: 0.000000>
...
(gdb) p (CGPoint)[0x6a3bd90 center]
$1 = {
  x = 100, 
  y = 111.5
}
```

So after a right angle rotation, you need to adjust the center point by a half-point on both the X and Y axes:

```
CGPoint center = slider.center;
center.x += .5;
center.y += .5;
slider.center = center;
```

so that the frame will lie on whole point boundaries:

```
(gdb) po [[(id)UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
<UIWindow: 0x9960aa0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x9962970>>
   | <UIView: 0x9964680; frame = (0 20; 320 460); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x9963c70>>
   |    | <UISlider: 0x9964020; frame = (89 92; 23 40); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9963010>; value: 0.000000>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for that! Here I was thinking I was going to have to rewrite UISlider for my app!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the location of the slider after rotation is on pixels, if it ends up in like 0.3, 0.2 it will be ugly, but if it ends up in 1, 1 it will look normal.
A specific problem I can see is if kWTFSliderHeight is odd. If it is, put it on 0.5, 0 before rotation and check